# Array with UIImageView elements - setImageWithURL

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have such code

```
arrayWithImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSEnumerator *enumForNames = [arrayWithNames objectEnumerator];
NSEnumerator *enumForURLs = [arrayWithURLs objectEnumerator];

id objName, objURL;

while(objName = [enumForNames nextObject]) {
    objURL = [enumForURLs nextObject];

    UIImageView *anImage = nil;
    [anImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:objURL]];

    (...)

    [arrayWithImages addObject:anImage];

}
```

And each time I got SIGABRT in line with "[arrayWithImages addObject:anImage];"
What's here wrong?

Comment: Check the log and publish stack trace

Comment: Did you check to see if the image got set properly? If it is still `nil` when you try to add it to the array, it will crash.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: Oh okay, just make sure it isn’t nil. Updated answer.

Comment: Here the answer - you try to insert `nil` object into array. Check `anImage` before you try insert it.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see an `setImageWithURL` method on `UIImageView`. Where is this from?

Is there any output from the SIGABRT crash?

Try this code:

```
// Download the image
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:objURL]];
// Make an UIImage out of it
UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
// Create an image view with the image
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:anImage];

// Check to make sure it exists
if (imageView != nil) {
    // Add it to your array
    [arrayWithImages addObject:imageView];
else {
    NSLog(@"Image view is nil");
}
```

Note that you should download the images asynchronously to avoid hanging the loop. [This blog post](http://www.alterplay.com/ios-dev-tips/2009/10/asynchronous-uiimage-from-web.html) discussing asynchronous image downloading.

Also if you know that `[enumForURLs nextObject];` will return an NSString (or even better, NSURL) you should assign `objURL` to type NSString (or NSURL).

Comment: setImageWithURL is a method of class SDWebImage. I got it properly imported I guess.

Comment: So how can I fix it using still setImageWithURL ?

Comment: the `if (imageView != nil) { [arrayWithImages addObject:imageView]; }` portion. Check the console and see how many/which ones are nil.